# How to trigger flow when the record is new or changed

Tags: administration, developer, sales-cloud, sales, flow-builder

I'd like to know when is the alternative method when using formula, ISNEW() and ISCHANGED() in the flow builder.

Here's what I already know:

- ISCHANGED() 
  1) Compare CreatedDate <> LastModificationDate 
  *Limits - **Cannot speicfied the field** 
  2) Call the flow using process builder 
  *Limits - Want to use a single method
  3) Use Field Tracking Object 
  *Limits - Can only track **less than 20 fields**
- ISNEW() 
  1) Compare CreatedDate == LastModificationDate 
  2) Call the flow using process builder 
  *Limits - Want to use a single method 
  3) Use Field Tracking Object; when it doesn't have any field updates history...? 

  I want to use these funtions to detect a specific field. (such as ISCHANGED(AccountId)) 
  It would be great if you share more effiecient ideas instead of using above ways!

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rita, what is your actual scenario, why do you want alternative for these functions?

Comment: Hi, Rahul. Currently, my team is planning to replace multiple process builders in one flow per the same object. My actual scenario was built by a process builder so I could use ISNEW() and ISCHANED() functions. However, as far as I know, the flow doesn't' support these two functions. That's why I need alternative solutions to filter records in the same condition.

Comment: I think merging those process builder into one is more appropriate here. instead of creating flow. is there specific reason to go with flows?

Comment: We want to go with flows because there are some limitations when using the process builder. 1) Hard to configure logic in order (This is the main reason why I cannot join the whole processes at once) 2) Cannot receive return value ...etc.

Comment: so you want the flow to be aware of the old/new versions of the record?

Comment: @cropredy Yes, if we are able to detect old/new values of specific fields, I think it works for us like ISCHANED().

Comment: flow doesn't work this way, the flow's invoker needs to detect old v. new condition; apex could pass in old and new recs as flow variables; PB can't